# Retrieve current and previous values using a query

Tags: sql

I need to retrieve current and previous odometer reading for any fuel order placed for a particular vehicle. I have used the query below, but previous odometer reading figures are not getting retrieved. What could I be doing wrong?.

this is the result I'm getting from the query:

```
doc#      doc_status     Vehicle      Fuel_type     Current       Previous
                                                    Odometer      Odometer
                                                    Reading       Reading

1902011    APPROVED   KAP 725W ISUZU  DIESEL        502199        NULL                                     
1902012    APPROVED   KBR 878U ISUZU  DIESEL        98094         NULL                               
1902013    APPROVED   KBR 877U ISUZU  DIESEL        150334        NULL                            
1902014    APPROVED   KBU 812T ISUZU  DIESEL        175166        NULL
```

This is the Query:

```
SELECT
  dbo.t_doc_data.docNo,
  dbo.t_doc_data.docstatus,
  dbo.t_doc_fuelorders.fovid,
  dbo.t_fuel_order_vehicles.vregno,
  dbo.t_doc_fuelorders.fofueltype,
  (SELECT
    MAX(foodometer)
  FROM dbo.t_doc_fuelorders
  WHERE docNo = dbo.t_doc_data.docNo
  AND fovid = t_doc_fuelorders.fovid)
  current_odometer_reading,
  (SELECT
    MAX(foodometer)
  FROM dbo.t_doc_fuelorders
  WHERE docNo = dbo.t_doc_data.docNo
  AND fovid = t_doc_fuelorders.fovid
  AND foodometer < (SELECT
    MAX(foodometer)
  FROM dbo.t_doc_fuelorders
  WHERE docNo = dbo.t_doc_data.docNo
  AND fovid = t_doc_fuelorders.fovid))
  previous_odometer_reading
FROM dbo.t_doc_data
INNER JOIN dbo.t_doc_fuelorders
  ON dbo.t_doc_data.docNo = dbo.t_doc_fuelorders.docNo
INNER JOIN dbo.t_fuel_order_vehicles
  ON dbo.t_doc_fuelorders.fovid = dbo.t_fuel_order_vehicles.vid
```

Comment: Please specify your db, SQL is a common reference.

Comment: You can use the `lag()` function to access values from the "previous" row.

Comment: lag() function did the trick. Thank you.